# query with LISTAGG() string function does not return the desired output

Tags: oracle-11g, window-functions, string-aggregation

I'm new to ORACLE and I'm trying to use a string aggregation function in my query to concatenate the value of rows with  a comma `,`

this is the structure of my tables:

1. Student(STUDENT_ID,student_name,age)
2. Course(course_no,description)
3. Student_Course(student_id,course_id,nomreh)

description column indicates the name of the course for example Algebra or Math. Nomreh column shows the Mark each student achieved in each course (it's a Persian word).

This is my query

```
Select s.student_name , 
   LISTAGG(c.description, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.description) AS 
          Courses,
   LISTAGG(sc.nomreh, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY sc.nomreh) AS Ranks
from student s inner join 
        student_course sc on s.student_id = sc.student_id 
           inner join
        course c on sc.course_id = c.course_no
 group by s.student_name
```

I want the output to show:

```
[Student-name]   [Course-Description]    [Nomre]
  Artin           Algebra,Math,Sport    10,11,12
```

each value in `[Nomreh]` column should be exactly for that `[Course]` column and for that specific student . Unfortunately my query does not give the desired output and the values in Nomreh column are not in correct order with [Course-Description] column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part of your query to the below:

```
       LISTAGG(c.description, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
                s.student_name,c.description,sc.nomreh) AS Courses,
       LISTAGG(sc.nomreh, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 
                s.student_name,c.description,sc.nomreh) AS Ranks
```